# RxJS: dynamically add and remove Observable with merge

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to build a pluggable `ProgressService`.

The service should track how many "things" are currently loading. And have an `isLoading()` method that returns an `Observable<boolean>` to indicate if anything is loading at all.

My first solution was very naive using a `new BehaviorSubject(0)` and then each loading provider just called `ProgressService.increase()` and `ProgressService.decrease()`. This worked fine. But now I'd like to go more reactive, if possible.

---

Then I came across `merge`, which works fine when all loading providers are known at the beginning:

```js
this.progress = merge(...progressProviders).pipe(
  scan((acc, curr) => acc + (curr ? 1 : -1), 0)
);
```

This will simply increase / decrease the `progress` value, when any loading provider emits `true` or `false`.

But I also need some kind of register / unregister functionality. This should basically add a new `Observable` to the `merge` chain (or remove it).

---

The new `ProgressService` should look like this:

```js
class ProgressService {

  progress: Observable<number> = EMPTY; // value > 0 when something is loading

  addLoadingProvider(lp: Observable<boolean>) {
    // increment this.progress, when lp emits true
    // decrease this.progress, when lp emits false
    // nice to have: ignore if lp's first emitted value is false
  }

  removeLoadingProvider(lp: Observable<boolean>) {
    // stop listening to lp
    // clean up: decrease this.progress, if lp last emitted true
  }

  isLoading(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.progress.pipe(
      map(val => val !== 0)
    );
  }

}
```

Maybe the `removeLoadingProvider` method isn't needed at all (?), if we return a `Subscription` from `addLoadingProvider`, and use `Subscription.unsubscribe()` to unregister.

Hopefully someone can tell me how to `merge` and `unmerge` additional Observables on demand.

Answer (score 2):

As per your explaination, I could understand the following [please correct me If my understanding is not correct] -

You want to collect various observables which emit boolean value and you want to keep track in such a way if any one of them is having at least one `"true"` then your final observable should emit true otherwise final observable should return `"false"`

Although your BehaviorSubject approach is a reactive approach. I am proposing the following approach; Let me know if it makes sense in your scenario -

**Approach 1 -**

```
enum ListAction {
  Added,
  Removed,
  Empty,
  Undefined
}

export class ProgressService {

  constructor() { }

  progress: Observable<number> = EMPTY; // value > 0 when something is loading

  obsListChanged: BehaviorSubject<ListAction> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(ListAction.Undefined);
  obsList: Array<Observable<boolean>> = [];

  addLoadingProvider(lp: Observable<boolean>) {
    // increment this.progress, when lp emits true
    // decrease this.progress, when lp emits false
    // nice to have: ignore if lp's first emitted value is false
    this.obsList.push(lp);

    this.obsListChanged.next(ListAction.Added);
  }

  removeLoadingProvider(lp: Observable<boolean>) {
    // stop listening to lp
    // clean up: decrease this.progress, if lp last emitted true
    this.obsList = this.obsList.filter(i => i !== lp);
    this.obsListChanged.next(ListAction.Removed);
  }

  isLoading(): Observable<boolean> {
    // return this.progress.pipe(
    //   map(val => val !== 0)
    // );
    return this.obsListChanged.pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return combineLatest(this.obsList);
      }),
      map(v => {
        return v.some(loading => loading);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

I have defined a ListAction observable if you want to do specific works as per your ListAction then you can do the same in rxjs operators as per your logic.

**Approach 2 [A bit improved version of Approach 1] -**

```
export class ProgressService {

  constructor() { }

  progress: Observable<number> = EMPTY; // value > 0 when something is loading

  obsList$: BehaviorSubject<Array<Observable<boolean>>> = new BehaviorSubject<Array<Observable<boolean>>>([]);

  addLoadingProvider(lp: Observable<boolean>) {
    // increment this.progress, when lp emits true
    // decrease this.progress, when lp emits false
    // nice to have: ignore if lp's first emitted value is false
    this.obsList$.next([...this.obsList$.getValue(), lp]);
  }

  removeLoadingProvider(lp: Observable<boolean>) {
    // stop listening to lp
    // clean up: decrease this.progress, if lp last emitted true
    const removed = this.obsList$.getValue().filter(i => i !== lp);
    this.obsList$.next(removed);
  }

  isLoading(): Observable<boolean> {
    // return this.progress.pipe(
    //   map(val => val !== 0)
    // );
    return this.obsList$.pipe(
      switchMap(obs => {
        return combineLatest(obs);
      }),
      map(v => {
        return v.some(loading => loading);
      })
    );
  }
}
```